# angular remove hash sign

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash

i am trying to make a directory structure for webapps in angularJS and my problem now is that i use $routeProvider and this adds me a hash sign (#) in the link. I tryed this function

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

but after i use thyis function, the routeProvider does not work anymore, it doesnt load any ng-view where it should. This is my routeprovider

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/', { templateUrl: '/view/home.html' })
            .when('/blog', { templateUrl: '/view/blog.html' })
            .when('/contact', { templateUrl: '/view/contact.html' })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

Is there another way to remove the hash and make the application not a single page application? Thank you, Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

Remove # from Url in angular project.

http://localhost/#/about  --->  http://localhost/about

1) Add base url in your index.html

2) use html5 history in your app.js or routes.js

```
if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

3) Server side configuration
    - Grunt Server:
    middleware: function (connect) {
        var middlewares = [];
        middlewares.push(modRewrite([
          '!/assets|\.html|\.js|\.css|\woff|\ttf|\swf$ /index.html'
        ]));

```
    middlewares.push(connect.static('.tmp'));
    middlewares.push(connect().use(
      '/bower_components',
      connect.static('./bower_components')
    ));
    middlewares.push(connect.static(appConfig.app));

    //middlewares.push(require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest);
    return middlewares;
  }

  -Ngnix Server  
  location ~ ^/(scripts.*js|styles|images) {
        gzip_static on;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header ETag "";
        break;
    }

   #location /api1 {
   #  rewrite ^/api1/(.*) /$1 break;
   #  proxy_redirect off;
   #  proxy_pass https://api1.example.com;
   #  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   #  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   #  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
   #  proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
   #}

   #location /api2 {
   #  rewrite ^/api2/(.*) /$1 break;
   #  proxy_redirect off;
   #  proxy_pass https://api2.example.com;
   #  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   #  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   #  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
   #  proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
   #}

   location / {
     try_files $uri /index.html;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need in the routes file, like you did:
    `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`
and you have to add to your index file, in the head:
    `<base href="/">`

Answer (score 0):

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')
```

And now u can use link like '/home' without `#` (only for html5-browsers)

Comment: it doesnt work, when i write refresh page it sends me to localhost root

Comment: U use both `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')` functions?

Comment: I am using both `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');`. And my href attribute: `<a href="/blog">Blog</a>`. It works for me. In the browser my links lokks like `localhost/blog`

Comment: the problem is i have the files inside a subfolder called pdaniel in www folder